Lines AM and AN are both the tangent of a circle with the center O, in what situation is OA the bisector of MN?
I've been recently stuck with the corresponding question in the title, after working it out for a while I came up with an answer: You can't.
Since AM and AN may be of any length.
But my question is, in what case and exceptions is OA the bisector of MN??

AM and AN will both have the same length though...


Unless $M$, $N$ are the same point, $AMO$ and $ANO$ are both right-angled triangles. Since $OM$ and $ON$ are both radii of the same circle, it follows that $AM$ and $AN$ have the same length.
This means $AMO$ and $ANO$ are congruent triangles and therefore $OA$ will always be the angle bisector.
Also by congruence of triangles, $OA$ will bisect the line segment $MN$.
If $N$ is to the right of point $O$ then it is not possible to draw the tangent, but I think the tangent being possible is assumed by how the question is written.
UPDATE Based on a comment below that $M$ and $N$ need not be on the circle for lines $AM$ and $AN$ to be tangents to the circle, perhaps a better answer is:
OA bisects MN if any only if M and N are on the circumference of the circle.

Technicality: We are never told that $M$ and $N$ are the points of tangency. It's not difficult to fix, but it does require some rephrasing here and there.

Kind of elaborated proof for "perpendicular from centre always bisects chord"

@Arthur in that case can we say anything? Say AMN is a triangle, with O as the incircle.  The median from A to MN is not bound to pass through O right?

Actually... I think this answers the question (in a round about way) - will update my answer.

If AM and AN are distinct lines, then OA will always be the angle bisector. The angle bisector is the median iff the triangle is isosceles. So that's the answer.

Brilliant explanation.
